# Jar is in class path but refuses to work

Tags: java, jar, classpath

My class path iS:

```
:.:/usr/share/java/*:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

**EDIT:**

IT also does not work if i have my class path set up as

```
:.:/usr/share/java/:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

Or

```
:.:/usr/share/java:/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

I know the directory contains the correct jar for the class i want to use but javac still gives me errors:

```
javac util/GSpreadsheets.java 
GSpreadsheets.java:1: package com.google.gdata does not exist
import com.google.gdata.*;
^
GSpreadsheets.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SpreadsheetService
location: class GSpreadsheets
    SpreadsheetService myService = null;
    ^
GSpreadsheets.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SpreadsheetFeed
location: class GSpreadsheets
    public SpreadsheetFeed getEventFeed() throws IOException,ServiceException{
           ^
GSpreadsheets.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SpreadseetService
location: class GSpreadsheets
            myService = new SpreadseetService("cl", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
                            ^
GSpreadsheets.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable metafeedUrl
location: class GSpreadsheets
        return service.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
                               ^
GSpreadsheets.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SpreadsheetFeed
location: class GSpreadsheets
        return service.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
                                            ^
GSpreadsheets.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable service
location: class GSpreadsheets
        return service.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
               ^
7 errors
```

If a manually specify the jar i need using -cp it works, sometimes. But if use -cp i have to manually specify each jar individually i want to use. Which is a pain in the ass.

the directory contains.

```
ls /usr/share/java/



activation-1.1.1.jar                          commons-digester.jar                  inetlib.jar                               lucene-spellchecker-2.9.4.jar
activation.jar                                commons-el-1.0.jar                    jasper-5.5.26.jar                         lucene-spellchecker.jar
ant-1.8.2.jar                                 commons-el.jar                        jaxp-1.3.jar                              lucene-surround-2.9.4.jar
ant-antlr-1.8.2.jar                           commons-httpclient-3.1.jar            jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar                  lucene-surround.jar
ant-antlr.jar                                 commons-httpclient.jar                jcl-over-slf4j.jar                        lucene-swing-2.9.4.jar
ant-apache-bcel-1.8.2.jar                     commons-logging-1.1.1.jar             jetty-6.1.24.jar                          lucene-swing.jar
ant-apache-bcel.jar                           commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar    jetty.jar                                 lucene-wikipedia-2.9.4.jar
ant-apache-bsf-1.8.2.jar                      commons-logging-adapters.jar          jetty-sslengine-6.1.24.jar                lucene-wikipedia.jar
ant-apache-bsf.jar                            commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar         jetty-sslengine.jar                       lucene-wordnet-2.9.4.jar
ant-apache-log4j-1.8.2.jar                    commons-logging-api.jar               jetty-start-6.1.24.jar                    lucene-wordnet.jar
ant-apache-log4j.jar                          commons-logging.jar                   jetty-start-daemon-6.1.24.jar             lucene-xml-query-parser-2.9.4.jar
ant-apache-oro-1.8.2.jar                      commons-pool-1.5.6.jar                jetty-start-daemon.jar                    lucene-xml-query-parser.jar
ant-apache-oro.jar                            commons-pool.jar                      jetty-start.jar                           mysql-5.1.10.jar
ant-apache-regexp-1.8.2.jar                   db-5.1.25.jar                         jetty-util5-6.1.24.jar                    mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar
ant-apache-regexp.jar                         db.jar                                jetty-util5.jar                           mysql-connector-java.jar
ant-apache-resolver-1.8.2.jar                 db-je-3.3.62.jar                      jetty-util-6.1.24.jar                     mysql.jar
ant-apache-resolver.jar                       db-je.jar                             jetty-util.jar                            org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.dist.jar
ant-apache-xalan2-1.8.2.jar                   ecj.jar                               jline-0.9.94.jar                          org.eclipse.osgi.jar
ant-apache-xalan2.jar                         eclipse-ecj-3.5.1.jar                 jline.jar                                 org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.0.dist.jar
ant-bootstrap.jar                             eclipse-ecj.jar                       jsch-0.1.42.jar                           org.eclipse.osgi.services.jar
ant-commons-logging-1.8.2.jar                 el-api-2.1.jar                        jsch.jar                                  org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.200.dist.jar
ant-commons-logging.jar                       gdata-analytics-2.1.jar               jsp-api-2.0.jar                           org.eclipse.osgi.util.jar
ant-commons-net-1.8.2.jar                     gdata-analytics-meta-2.1.jar          jsp-api-2.1.jar                           org.sat4j.core-2.3.0.jar
ant-commons-net.jar                           gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0.jar       jsp-api.jar                               org.sat4j.core.jar
ant.jar                                       gdata-appsforyourdomain-meta-1.0.jar  jtidy-8.0-alpha-20110807.jar              org.sat4j.pb-2.3.0.jar
ant-javamail-1.8.2.jar                        gdata-base-1.0.jar                    jtidy.jar                                 org.sat4j.pb.jar
ant-javamail.jar                              gdata-blogger-2.0.jar                 jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar                    regexp-1.5.jar
ant-jdepend-1.8.2.jar                         gdata-blogger-meta-2.0.jar            jul-to-slf4j.jar                          regexp.jar
ant-jdepend.jar                               gdata-books-1.0.jar                   junit-3.8.2.jar                           sat4j-pb-2.3.0.jar
ant-jmf-1.8.2.jar                             gdata-books-meta-1.0.jar              junit4-4.8.2.jar                          sat4j-pb.jar
ant-jmf.jar                                   gdata-calendar-2.0.jar                junit4.jar                                servlet-api-2.4.jar
ant-jsch-1.8.2.jar                            gdata-calendar-meta-2.0.jar           junit.jar                                 servlet-api-2.5.jar
ant-jsch.jar                                  gdata-client-1.0.jar                  lib                                       servlet-api.jar
ant-junit-1.8.2.jar                           gdata-client.jar                      libgcj-4.6.1.jar                          slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
ant-junit.jar                                 gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar             libgcj-4.6.jar                            slf4j-api.jar
ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar                        gdata-codesearch-2.0.jar              libgcj-tools-4.6.1.jar                    slf4j-jcl-1.6.1.jar
ant-launcher.jar                              gdata-codesearch-meta-2.0.jar         libgcj-tools-4.6.jar                      slf4j-jcl.jar
ant-swing-1.8.2.jar                           gdata-contacts-3.0.jar                libintl.jar                               slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
ant-swing.jar                                 gdata-contacts-meta-3.0.jar           log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar                slf4j-jdk14.jar
ant-testutil-1.8.2.jar                        gdata-core-1.0.jar                    log4j-over-slf4j.jar                      slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
ant-testutil.jar                              gdata-docs-3.0.jar                    lucene-analyzers-2.9.4.jar                slf4j-log4j12.jar
asm3-3.3.2.jar                                gdata-docs-meta-3.0.jar               lucene-analyzers.jar                      slf4j-migrator-1.6.1.jar
asm3-all-3.3.2.jar                            gdata-finance-2.0.jar                 lucene-ant-2.9.4.jar                      slf4j-migrator.jar
asm3-all.jar                                  gdata-finance-meta-2.0.jar            lucene-ant.jar                            slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar
asm3-analysis-3.3.2.jar                       gdata-gtt-2.0.jar                     lucene-bdb-2.9.4.jar                      slf4j-nop.jar
asm3-analysis.jar                             gdata-gtt-meta-2.0.jar                lucene-bdb.jar                            slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
asm3-commons-3.3.2.jar                        gdata-health-2.0.jar                  lucene-bdb-je-2.9.4.jar                   slf4j-simple.jar
asm3-commons.jar                              gdata-health-meta-2.0.jar             lucene-bdb-je.jar                         tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.21.jar
asm3-debug-all-3.3.2.jar                      gdata-maps-2.0.jar                    lucene-benchmark-2.9.4.jar                tomcat-annotations-api.jar
asm3-debug-all.jar                            gdata-maps-meta-2.0.jar               lucene-benchmark.jar                      tomcat-api-7.0.21.jar
asm3.jar                                      gdata-media-1.0.jar                   lucene-collation-2.9.4.jar                tomcat-api.jar
asm3-tree-3.3.2.jar                           gdata-photos-2.0.jar                  lucene-collation.jar                      tomcat-catalina-7.0.21.jar
asm3-tree.jar                                 gdata-photos-meta-2.0.jar             lucene-core-2.9.4.jar                     tomcat-catalina-ha-7.0.21.jar
asm3-util-3.3.2.jar                           gdata-projecthosting-2.1.jar          lucene-core.jar                           tomcat-catalina-ha.jar
asm3-util.jar                                 gdata-projecthosting-meta-2.1.jar     lucene-fast-vector-highlighter-2.9.4.jar  tomcat-catalina.jar
asm3-xml-3.3.2.jar                            gdata-sidewiki-2.0.jar                lucene-fast-vector-highlighter.jar        tomcat-coyote-7.0.21.jar
asm3-xml.jar                                  gdata-sidewiki-meta-2.0.jar           lucene-highlighter-2.9.4.jar              tomcat-coyote.jar
catalina-ant-7.0.21.jar                       gdata-sites-2.0.jar                   lucene-highlighter.jar                    tomcat-el-api-2.2.jar
catalina-ant.jar                              gdata-sites-meta-2.0.jar              lucene-instantiated-2.9.4.jar             tomcat-i18n-es-7.0.21.jar
catalina-tribes-7.0.21.jar                    gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar             lucene-instantiated.jar                   tomcat-i18n-es.jar
catalina-tribes.jar                           gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar        lucene-lucli-2.9.4.jar                    tomcat-i18n-fr-7.0.21.jar
com.ibm.icu-4.0.1.1.jar                       gdata-webmastertools-2.0.jar          lucene-lucli.jar                          tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
com.ibm.icu-4.4.jar                           gdata-webmastertools-meta-2.0.jar     lucene-memory-2.9.4.jar                   tomcat-i18n-ja-7.0.21.jar
com.ibm.icu.base-4.0.1.1.jar                  gdata-youtube-2.0.jar                 lucene-memory.jar                         tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
com.ibm.icu.base-4.4.jar                      gdata-youtube-meta-2.0.jar            lucene-misc-2.9.4.jar                     tomcat-jasper-7.0.21.jar
com.ibm.icu.base.jar                          gnome-java-bridge.jar                 lucene-misc.jar                           tomcat-jasper-el-7.0.21.jar
com.ibm.icu.jar                               gnumail-1.1.2.jar                     lucene-queries-2.9.4.jar                  tomcat-jasper-el.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar                   gnumail.jar                           lucene-queries.jar                        tomcat-jasper.jar
commons-beanutils.jar                         gnumail-providers-1.1.2.jar           lucene-queryparser-2.9.4.jar              tomcat-jsp-api-2.2.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar                         gnumail-providers.jar                 lucene-queryparser.jar                    tomcat-juli-7.0.21.jar
commons-codec.jar                             hamcrest-core-1.1.jar                 lucene-regex-2.9.4.jar                    tomcat-juli.jar
commons-collections3-3.2.1.jar                hamcrest-core.jar                     lucene-regex.jar                          tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar
commons-collections3.jar                      hamcrest-generator-1.1.jar            lucene-remote-2.9.4.jar                   tomcat-util-7.0.21.jar
commons-collections3-testframework-3.2.1.jar  hamcrest-generator.jar                lucene-remote.jar                         tomcat-util.jar
commons-collections3-testframework.jar        hamcrest-integration-1.1.jar          lucene-smartcn-2.9.4.jar                  xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
commons-compress-1.0.jar                      hamcrest-integration.jar              lucene-smartcn.jar                        xercesImpl.jar
commons-compress.jar                          hamcrest-library-1.1.jar              lucene-snowball-2.9.4.jar                 xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar                          hamcrest-library.jar                  lucene-snowball.jar                       xml-apis.jar
commons-dbcp.jar                              icu4j.jar                             lucene-spatial-2.9.4.jar                  xmlParserAPIs.jar
```

On a side note why isn't the code block honoring new line characters?

Comment: what is the command line? -classpath does support wildcard, but there are some restrictions : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: If you are running on Linux, make sure to escape your wildcard, otherwise you will face shell expansion. For example, use `java -cp lib/\* com.mycompany.Main`

Comment: My Command line is simply 'javac javafile.java' I have the $CLASSPATH set up as an environment variable. I am trying to not use -cp in my command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below syntax to include all jars present in particular directory in class path.

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$(find $REQUIRED_DIRECTORY -name "*.jar"|tr "\n" ":")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use * in the classpath. You should specify each jar separately.